# Accessing SQL Server Without Logging into VPN

Tags: sql, sql-server, vpn

We have a web application that runs on Windows Server 2008 that needs to access a SQL Server database on that server. How we normally connect up to the SQL Server is by logging into the VPN. How would I go about opening port 1433 as a pass-through. This way, my web application can connect up to SQL Server without  being logged on to the VPN.

Thank you in advance,
Jim

Comment: What language is your web application written in? It sounds like you need to set up a datasource with the SQL Server's login credentials.

Comment: My application is written in ASP.net 4.0. We have our connection string in the web config, encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If the DB server *and port* is accessible at TCP/IP level w/o the VPN then is possible, just run your app under [`runas /netonly`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx). But, even if the DB server host is accessible, but if the DB server is no *listening* on a Internet accessible IP then you cannot reach it. A good deployment should not expose the DB listenning to the internet, is a hack waiting to happen, so VPN should be *required* if the DB server is properly configured. Therefore, if you do manage to conenct w/o the VPN, reconfigure the DB server in a way in which you fail to connect w/o a VPN. The server security should trump your convenience...

Comment: As mentioned above, I am running ASP.net so I do not have that option "runas /netonly" or at least I have never heard of that.

Comment: I think http://www.pseale.com/pretend-youre-on-the-domain-with-runas-netonly is relevant here